# How do you return the results of all the methods of a class object as one list?

Tags: python, list, class, methods

How do you return the results of all the methods of a class object as one list?

```
class Example(object):

  def Calc1(self):
     return 1

  def Calc3(self):
     return 2

  def Calc5(self):
     return 3


Desired_Result = [1,2,3]
```

I don't want to use the common method like this:

```
Desired_Result = [Example().Calc1(),Example().Calc3(),Example().Calc5()]
```

I want the function to be scalable in that the class can have ten or hundreds of methods, so that I wouldn't have to type each method.

Also, bonus points for getting the names of the methods as well.

```
Desired_Result2 = ['Calc1','Calc3','Calc5']
```

Comment: What if the methods have parameters?

Comment: I'm not concerned about parameters yet, as I'm only interested in methods without parameters currently. However, that would be really helpful if there was a way to do this for methods with parameters, but not sure how possible that is.

Comment: Well, it's not possible unless you expect to get the return value for every possible parameter (which may be infinitely many) for every method. What are you actually trying to achieve by doing this? There may be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import inspect
# Class def here
instance = ClassDef()
methods = {m[0]: m[1] for m in inspect.getmembers(instance) if inspect.ismethod(m[1])}
method_results = {k: v() for k, v in methods.items()}  # only works for methods that take only one argument (the instance)
```

Note that the last line above will only work with methods that take a single argument (the instance). You can get the name combined with the result of the method as follows:

```
print method_results
{'Calc1': 1, 'Calc3': 2, 'Calc5': 3}
```

And just the results of the methods:

```
print [v() for v in method_results.values()]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I prefer this approach, but I think you need to take this approach one step further. The OP wants the output of each of those methods. That is to say, the OP wants the names *and* `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Try this instead and in addition to what you already have: `methods = {m[0]: m[1] for m in inspect.getmembers(instance) if inspect.ismethod(m[1])}`. `{k: v() for k, v in methods.items()}`

Comment: Feel free to undo my edits if you are not happy with my modification.

Answer (score 1):

Note [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451090/how-do-you-return-the-results-of-all-the-methods-of-a-class-object-as-one-list/23451170#comment35948143_23451127) (and now edit) on AMacK's answer. I think that answer is best. For the record, though, I originally proposed this as another viable (and now less preferable) alternative:

```
>>> e = Example()  # create a generic instance
>>> methods = {k: v for k, v in Example.__dict__.items() if hasattr(v, '__call__')}
>>> [v(e) for v in methods.values()]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> {k: v(e) for k, v in methods.items()}  # will only work if all methods take only one argument, the instance
{'Calc1': 1, 'Calc3': 2, 'Calc5': 3}
```

Note that this approach (and AMacK's current approach) will only work for methods that require one argument (the instance).